# Animation in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I want to reuse the code and make it work for both mobile devices and other devices. Specifically, when I am on a mobile device I want the same animation but with different text to appear and when I am on a laptop or desktop, I want the same animation with different text to appear.

So essentially, there should be one single animation but it should have text that works differently for mobile devices and another text that works for laptops or desktops or larger screens.

Code:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html3,
body3 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner3 {
 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}
.exponea-banner3.exponea-in3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-close3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-text3 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-count3 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3,
.exponea-close3,
.exponea-text3,
.exponea-label3,
.exponea-label3 {
    z-index: 10;
}
.open3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
        <div class="exponea-close3">
            &times;
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-text3">
            Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-label3">
            - Hussain Omer
        </div>
    </div>
```

The text in the above animation should only work on **laptops/desktops/larger screens**

---

Now, I want the **same** animation but the **different** text that says "Hi, please use a large device for the best experience" to work **only** on mobile devices.

When the user is on the mobile device, the text should say what I said above and when the user is on laptops/desktops/large screen then the text should say what I sent in the code. Any suggestions on how I can toggle the text in the animation?

tl;dr: I want the same animation but when the user is on a mobile device, it should have a text saying "Hi, please use a large device for the best experience" but when the user is on a laptop/desktop or large screen device, then the text should say what it is in the code I sent above.

This is what I was suggested by someone to do but it does not seem to work:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

// Media query example
const isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 360px)')

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');

    if(isMobile) {
       document.querySelector(".exponea-text3").textContent = "Hi, please use a large 
        device for the best experience"
    }

    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited your snippet a bit and it's working now. Basically I'm using JQuery to check device width and perform actions (also there is an ID added to the HTML tag containing the changing text).

You can check this page with your phone and see the results.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  //checks if the device's max width is more than 600px or less
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches) {
    (function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      
        //adds the text
        $('#changingText').text('Please check my website with a larger device!')
        
        var banner;
        banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
        banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');

        return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
          return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
        });
      });

    }).call(this);
  } else {
    (function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      
        //adds the text
        $('#changingText').text('Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!')
        
        var banner;
        banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
        banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');

        return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
          return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
        });
      });

    }).call(this);
  }


});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html3,
body3 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner3 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}

.exponea-banner3.exponea-in3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.exponea-banner3 .exponea-close3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner3 .exponea-text3 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.exponea-banner3 .exponea-count3 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner3,
.exponea-close3,
.exponea-text3,
.exponea-label3,
.exponea-label3 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.open3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
  <div class="exponea-close3">
    &times;
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="changingText" class="exponea-text3"></div>
  
  <div class="exponea-label3">
    - Hussain Omer
  </div>
</div>
```